# Binding to DependencyProperty not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I've created DP in the following way:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SchoolsViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SchoolsViewModel", typeof(SchoolsViewModel), typeof(SchoolChooser), new PropertyMetadata(default(SchoolsViewModel)));
 public SchoolsViewModel SchoolsViewModel
 {
    get
    {
        return (SchoolsViewModel)GetValue(SchoolsViewModelProperty);
    }

    set
    {
       SetValue(SchoolsViewModelProperty, value);
       this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
 private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }
```

Next, I'm binding it to the DataContext:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SchoolChooserPage, Path=SchoolsViewModel}"/>
```

Then, I'm setting property in costructor:

```
public SchoolChooser()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.SchoolsViewModel = new SchoolsViewModel { Schools = TypeService.Resolve<ISchoolContext>().Schools };
}
```

Infortunately, DataContext is always null. It seems to me, that binding is not working. I've no idea why, such a way was working in wpf.

When I set DataContext directly like:

```
this.DataContext = this.SchoolsViewModel;
```

everything is fine. Why? What's, althought I've implement INotfiyProperyChanged, the event ProperyChanged is null.

Comment: When a binding fails, you will see the error in the Output window if you have the debugger attached.  Look in the output window and edit your question to include the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged` with `DependencyProperty`s. Maybe removing that will give you a better view on the problem.

I wonder why your View has a property for the viewmodel. Shouldn't the viewmodel go into the DataContext? I would expect your View and ViewModel to be independent with another instance like the `Application` creating both objects and connecting them by setting the Views `DataContext` to the ViewModel instance.

Example:

```
var view = new View();
var viewModel = new ViewModel();

view.DataContext = viewModel;

view.Show();
```

Comment: It's also not working without INotifyProperyChanged. The problem is that I do not now how to naviagate Pages in windows Rt. The only way I know is `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage))` so don't have possibility to change DataContext property (I'm passing a type, not instance)